# Can my MVC view display only the date portion of a SQL datetime field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application that is displaying the full datetime value from SQL (e.g. "1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM") and I'm trying to get it to only display the date (e.g. "1/1/2012").

My Index.cshtml file for the view in question pull the item in using this code:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OccurrenceDate)
```

Is there a way to modify this to only show the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also decorate your model with an annotation and the formatting will be handled for you

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
class myModel {
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  public DateTime OccurencDate {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Where would I put this? In the cshtml file? Or in the Model or Controller?

Comment: I found it. I added your code to my Occurrence.cs Controller and it worked great (much better than the other solution I found). I did have to add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;`. Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't add it to your controller. You would add it to your model definition. And yes, you need to use DataAnnotations.

Comment: Oh man. I think I've made my project extra confusing. I named my model file OccurrenceController.cs. Doh.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the <strike>[`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)property</strike> [`ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) method:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OccurrenceDate.ToShortDateString())
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I tried that and it doesn't change the display at all. I still get date and time.

Comment: @Splendor - try `ToShortDateString()` instead.

Comment: That gave me an InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use Html Helper DisplayFor unless you are taking an advantage of templates, which this helper is actually designed to do.

For your case just write:

```
@Model.OccurrenceDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy")
```

Comment: That gave me this error: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PtoTracker.Occurrence>' does not contain a definition for 'OccurrenceDate' and no extension method 'OccurrenceDate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PtoTracker.Occurrence>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked:

```
@String.Format("{0:d}", item.OccurrenceDate)
```

Source: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me
@item.OpeningDate.Value.ToShortDateString()

Comment: Its good to describe your answer even if it works. It will help others to understand the issue more clearly.

Comment: Try to describe your answer rather than dumping the code only.